# How to show "Welcome Back <Name>" Google Play popup when start the game with LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I use `libGDX` tools and `BaseGameUtils.GameHelper` in my project.
Every thing looks perfect and all functional works good.

Sign In, Sign out, Achievements, Leaderboards everything work normally.
Except `"Welcome Back <Name>"` popups that didn't show up when I start my game.
As I said, all functional works fine. My game automatically start sign in when game started.

But when I force sign out and sign in again.
In sign in flow process will bring up the `Google Play Services` green dialog prompt user to sign in.
After I clicked in `Sign In`, My game took time a while to connect to server and show `Welcome Back` popup.
In this section the popup appear to my game. I'm so very confusing why it works.

I test many time with my real device.
I notice that `Welcome Back` popup don't show if you didn't enter `Google Play Services` diglog before. I think it maybe some wrong configuration or my miss-understanding.

I try to use  `setViewForPopups` but it didn't work.
I want to setup `ViewForPopups` before `GoogleApiClient` connected.
But there are a lot of error when I use this way.

The last thing, it's not only happen with `Welcome Back` popup.
It also a `achievements` popup when I achieve something.

Here my part of code :

```
package com.huskybear.polyknock.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.huskybear.polyknock.Core.IGoogleServices;

public class AndroidGGServicesHelper implements IGoogleServices {

    private final static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private final static int RC_LEADER_BOARDS = 9002;
    private final static int RC_ACHIEVEMENTS = 9003;

    private GameHelper Helper;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;

    private Runnable callback = null;
    private View popups;

    private boolean isSignIn = false;
    private boolean isStartAutoFlow = false;

    public AndroidGGServicesHelper(Activity act, View popups) {

        this.mActivity = act;
        this.mContext = act.getApplicationContext();
        this.popups = popups;

        Helper = new GameHelper(act, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES | GameHelper.CLIENT_PLUS);
        GameHelper.GameHelperListener helperListener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSignInFailed() {
                if (isStartAutoFlow) {
                    Toast("Unable to sign in.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback.run();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                isSignIn = true;
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.run();
                }
            }
        };
        Helper.setConnectOnStart(false);
        Helper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
        Helper.setup(helperListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void signIn(final boolean isAutoFlow) {
        try {
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (isAutoFlow) {
                        isStartAutoFlow = true;
                        Helper.reconnectClient();
                    } else {
                        Helper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log in failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void signOut() {
        try {
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                //@Override
                public void run() {
                    Helper.signOut();
                    isSignIn = false;
                    Toast("Sign out complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback.run();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.log("MainActivity", "Log out failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void achievementUnlock(String type) {
        try {
            Games.Achievements.unlock(Helper.getApiClient(), type);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScore(int type, long score) {

    }

    @Override
    public void rateGame() {

        Games.setViewForPopups(Helper.getApiClient(), popups);
    }

    @Override
    public void showLeaderboards() {
        try {
            if (isConnected()) {
                mActivity.startActivityForResult(
                        Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(Helper.getApiClient()),
                        RC_LEADER_BOARDS
                );
            } else {
                signIn(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Helper.reconnectClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showAchievements() {
        try {
            if (isConnected()) {
                mActivity.startActivityForResult(
                        Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(Helper.getApiClient()),
                        RC_ACHIEVEMENTS
                );
            } else {
                signIn(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Helper.reconnectClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        try {
            Helper.onStart(mActivity);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Helper.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {
        Helper.disconnect();
        isSignIn = false;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (((requestCode == RC_LEADER_BOARDS) || (requestCode == RC_ACHIEVEMENTS))
                && resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
            Helper.disconnect();
            isSignIn = false;
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.run();
            }
        } else {
            Helper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return Helper.isSignedIn();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSignIn() {
        return isSignIn;
    }

    @Override
    public void Toast(final String text, final int length) {
        try {
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, text, length).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setCallback(Runnable run) {
        callback = run;
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad language.